# Use camera from web page?

Tags: camera

Is it possible to use/control the camera from (or at least initially from) a web page? I'd like to come in as a web page (not an app) but then be able to take a picture or pictures and package them into some web service calls.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, websites can use the WebRTC extension to access the phone's camera, with the user's permission. Not all browsers support this extension, but Chrome for Android does.

Answer (score 0):

There are different approaches to achieve that goal:

- using a "Cam Server" app on the Android device, and have it uploading pages to a web server
- same, but streaming
- same, with integrated web server (so no separate upload)
- having a fully integrated and programmable solution

For all four approaches you'll find matching apps. For the latter, I think e.g. of [Paw Server](http://www.appbrain.com/app/de.fun2code.android.pawserver), including a web server with scripting support. For "Cam Servers", you might wish to take a look into [this list](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=cat;id=155).